# If $y$ simplifies to $a\pi + $b then find ($a – b$), for the following condition.

Tags: trigonometry

Let $y=\sin^{-1}(\sin 8)–\tan^{-1}(\tan 10)+\cos^{-1}(\cos 12)–\sec^{-1}(\sec 9) +\cot^{-1}(\cot 6)– \mathrm{cosec}^{-1}(\mathrm{cosec} 7)$.

If  $y$ simplifies to  $a\pi + $b  then find ($a – b$)

My attempt is as follows:-

$$\sin^{-1}(\sin 8)=3\pi-8$$
$$\tan^{-1}(\tan 10)=-3\pi+10$$
$$\cos^{-1}(\cos 12)=4\pi-12$$
$$\sec^{-1}(\sec 9)=3\pi-9$$
$$\cot^{-1}(\cot 6)=2\pi-6$$
$$\mathrm{cosec}^{-1}(\mathrm{cosec} 7)=7-2\pi$$

$$y=(3\pi-8)+(3\pi-10)+(4\pi-12)-(3\pi-9)+(2\pi-6)-(7-2\pi)$$
$$y=11\pi-34$$

so $a=11, b=-34$, hence $a-b=11+34=45$

But actual answer is $53$, I don't know where I am going wrong. I checked the solution lot of times but didn't get any breakthrough.

Answer (score 2):

I got my mistake

$$\sec^{-1}(\sec 9)=-2\pi+9$$
$$\cot^{-1}(\cot 6)=-\pi+6$$

others are fine

$$y=(3\pi-8)+(3\pi-10)+(4\pi-12)+(2\pi-9)+(6-\pi)+(2\pi-7)$$
$$y=13\pi-40$$

So $a=13$,$b=-40$, hence $a-b=53$

I also wanted to discuss a short trick for solving such questions where we have to calculate $\sin^{-1}(\sin x),\cos^{-1}(\cos x),\tan^{-1}(\tan x)\cdots\cdots$ in a very short time.

**But before reading this trick, please see and draw the graphs of these functions, otherwise you will have to cram this.**

**Mainly for people who are preparing for competitive exams:-**

**Step-$1$**

**$1)$** Make all the values positive as follows:-

$$\sin^{-1}(\sin (-x))=-\sin^{-1}(\sin x)$$
$$\tan^{-1}(\tan (-x))=-\tan^{-1}(\sin x)$$
$$\mathrm{cosec}^{-1}(\mathrm{cosec} (-x))=-\mathrm{cosec}^{-1}(\mathrm{cosec} x)$$

$$\cos^{-1}(\cos (-x))=\pi-\cos^{-1}(\cos x)$$
$$\cot^{-1}(\cot (-x))=\pi-\cot^{-1}(\cot x)$$
$$\sec^{-1}(\sec (-x))=\pi-\sec^{-1}(\sec x)$$

This is pretty standard stuff, so nothing new.

**Step-$2$**- For $\sin^{-1}(\sin x),\tan^{-1}(\tan x),\mathrm{cosec}^{-1}\mathrm{cosec}(x)$

i) Get the nearest integer multiples of $\pi$ for $x$

Like for $\sin^{-1}(\sin 8)$
$$2\pi<=8<=3\pi$$

ii) Now check if $x$ is closer to lower or upper bound, like in the above case $8$ is closer to $3\pi$.

iii) Now the idea is that $\sin^{-1}(\sin x)$ should be positive, as $x$ is positive, so if $x$ is closer to lower bound then answer is **$x-$ lower-bound** otherwise **upper-bound $-x$**

$$8 \text { is closer to } 3\pi$$ 
Hence answer is 
$$\sin^{-1}(\sin 8)=3\pi-8$$

**Step-$2$**- For $\cos^{-1}(\cos x),\sec^{-1}(\sec x)$

i) Get the nearest odd multiples of $\pi$ for $x$ $(2n-1)\pi<=x<=(2n+1)\pi$

Like for $\sec^{-1}(\sec 9)$
$$\pi<=9<=3\pi$$

ii) Just see if $x$ lies between $(2n-1)\pi<=x<=2n\pi\quad$ or $\quad2n\pi<=x<=(2n+1)\pi$

$$2\pi<=9<=3\pi$$

iii) Now again the idea is that $\cos^{-1}(\cos x)$ should be positive as range of $\cos^{-1}(\cos x)$ is $\left[0,\pi\right]$. So if $(2n-1)\pi<=x<=2n\pi$, then answer is $2n\pi-x$, otherwise $x-2n\pi$

Hence $$\sec^{-1}(\sec 9)=9-2\pi$$

**Step-$2$**- For $\cot^{-1}(\cot x)$

i) Get the nearest integer multiples of $\pi$ for $x$

Like for $\cot^{-1}(\cot 6)$
$$\pi<=6<=2\pi$$

ii) Answer will be **$x-$ lower-bound** as again the idea is $\cot^{-1}(\cot x)$ should be positive as range of $\cot^{-1}(\cot x)$ is $\left[0,\pi\right]$.

So $$\cot^{-1}(\cot 6)=6-\pi$$

I hope this will be helpful.